# Процедурная генерация уровня

Tags: c#, unity3d, процедурная-генерация

Суть такая, пилю процедурную генерацию уровня из готовых комнат/модулей.

---

[image: Пример блока]

---

Какие есть способы соединить комнаты? 
Что бы следующая комната автоматически пристраивалась справа от предыдущей

### [image: Пример]

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

черные прямоугольники наша начальная карта,т к размеры модулей мы знаем,то знаем левую границу и правую (х1 и х2 далее)

далее по-надобности,спавним остальные модули по х координатам и сразу,при спавне нового модуля,меняем х1 или х2,чтобы следующий модуль встал на свое место

**Ps** изменять х - координаты можно в зависимости от разных модулей,например через switch,тк длина модулей может отличаться

Answer (score 0):

Я так сделал. В апдэйте, если позиция камеры по х больше BG1 плюс сколько то юнитов (чтобы заранее BG1 не Телепортнулся), меняем позицию относительно начальной position.x

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TileBG : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform BG1;//кидаете сюда 1 Background
public Transform BG2;//
public Transform cam;//камера



private void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    if (cam.position.x > BG1.localPosition.x + 2.4f){
        BG1.localPosition = new Vector3(BG1.localPosition.x + 4f, 0, 0);
    }

    if (cam.position.x > BG2.localPosition.x + 1.5f)
    {
        BG2.localPosition = new Vector3(BG2.localPosition.x + 4f, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: С чего это вдруг вы сравниваете localPosition и worldPosition? Легко можно выдумать пример, который сломает данный код. Более того, if-else абсолютно не расширяем для n-го числа разных комнат.